# Approximation for a Bessel function integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, bessel-functions, numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate hit probabilities on a dart board if the dart thrower has some Gaussian angle distribution function with width $\Delta$ and some systematic angle offsets $\phi_0, \theta_0$. This is a problem related to my work.

The distribution function is

$p(\theta, \phi) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \Delta^2} e^{-\frac{(\phi-\phi_0)^2}{2\Delta^2}}e^{-\frac{(\theta-\theta_0)^2}{2\Delta^2}}$

To get the hit probability on the dart boad, this distribution function must be integrated over a circle centered around 0 with some radius $R$ at a far away distance $D$.

So far I turned in into an integral in circle coordinates and now I'm stuck with this bad boy:

$p_{tot} = e^{-\rho_0^2} \int_0^{\frac{R}{\sqrt{2} D \Delta}} d\rho \rho e^{-\rho^2} I_0(2\rho \rho_0)$

where $\rho = \sqrt{\phi^2 + \theta^2}$ and $\rho_0$ equivalently. $I_0$ is the 0th modified Bessel function.

Any ideas on how to properly evaluate this? I'd be happy about a reasonable approximation.
Taylor expansions don't really work because the function in the integral has a peak that shifts to the right with increasing $\rho_0$. The area under the peak will grow like $e^{\rho_0^2}$ which can lead to some numerical issues but I guess I can approximate it with a delta distribution for really large $\rho_0$.

Comment: (i) What is actually your integral in terms of $\phi$ and $\theta$? (ii) Why does $D$ not enter your expression for $p_{tot}$? (iii) What do you mean by "far away distance $D$? That $D\to\infty$ (iv) Can you state your question formally, without darts, " far away distance", ...?

Comment: (v) How can angles, with values (say) in $[0,2\pi)$, be normally distributed? (vi) Is $\Delta$ small?

Comment: (i) The integral is over $\int \int p(\theta,\phi) d\theta d\phi$ and the limits are a circle with radius $R/D$ around (0,0). (ii) D is in the upper limit of the integral. (iii) R/D <<1 (iv) sorry, physicist (v) and (vi) $\Delta << 1$

Comment: (I) Can it be assumed that $R/D$ is much greater than $\Delta^2$ (and $R/D$ is much less than $1$)? (II) Can $\rho_0>0$ be assumed fixed? (III) Your expression for $p_{tot}$ is incorrect. (IV) Does your symbol $<<$ mean "much less"?

Comment: (i) No. (ii) No, I need a range of values for $\rho_0$ (iii) There may be a factor missing that's not really relevant for the Bessel integral. (iv) yes.

Comment: Without (I) and (II), there are a number of different kinds of asymptotics. I am not sure there will be someone willing to spend time to adequately cover all those cases. Concerning (II), can we at least assume that $\rho_0$ is on the order of $1$ (not $<<1$ and not $>>1$)?

Comment: $\rho_0$ can be very small or very large. Anyway I think from the discussions here I figured out that I can probably get a good solution by Taylor expansion of I0 for small $\rho_0$, and by doing the replacement with $e^x/\sqrt{2 \pi x}$ and Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{\rho}$ for large $\rho_0$. So, thanks for your help.

Comment: @mzw : I added the plots for the small-$\rho_0$ approximation; as you can see, you don't really need $\rho_0$ to be "very" small or large.

Comment: @mzw : As noted before, your expression for $p_{tot}$ is incorrect. It should be clear that $p_{tot}$ is a function of the **dimensionless** quantities $\rho_0/\Delta$ and $r/\Delta$, where $r:=R/D$. So, the conditions $R/D<<1$ and $\Delta<<1$ make no sense, because $R/D$ and $\Delta$ are not dimensionless and therefore cannot be compared to $1$. To get a definite asymptotic, you need to say about each of the three ratios --  $\rho_0/\Delta$, $r/\Delta$, and $\rho_0/r$ (or at least two relevant ratios -- say $\rho_0/\Delta$ and $r\rho_0/\Delta^2$) whether it is $>>1$, $<<1$, or $\asymp1$.

Comment: @mzw : At least, can we assume that $\Delta/\rho_0<<1$? (Which would be a meaningful replacement of the meaningless condition $\Delta<<1$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** The OP seeks a "reasonable approximation" for large or small $\rho_0$ of the function
$$P(x)= \int_0^{x}   e^{-\rho^2-\rho_0^2} \rho I_0(2\rho \rho_0)\,d\rho,\;\;x\geq 0.$$

---

Consider the kernel
$$p_{\rm exact}(\rho)=e^{-\rho^2-\rho_0^2} \rho  I_0(2\rho \rho_0).$$
For small $\rho_0$ a Taylor series in powers of $\rho_0$ is accurate,
$$p_{\rm small}(\rho)=e^{-\rho^2} \rho (1+\rho^2 \rho_0^2-\rho_0^2).$$
For large $\rho_0$ an asymptotic expansion of the Bessel function gives
$$p_{\rm large}(\rho)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\rho^2-\rho_0^2}e^{2\rho\rho_0}.$$

In the plots below I compare $\int_0^x p(\rho)\,d\rho$ for the exact expression (blue) and the approximation (orange). It turns out the approximations $p_{\rm small}$ and $p_{\rm large}$ are already quite accurate for $\rho_0\lesssim 0.5$ and $\rho_0\gtrsim 3$, respectively.

[image]
[image]


Left plot: comparison of $\int_0^x p_{\rm exact}(\rho)\,d\rho$ and $\int_0^x p_{\rm small}(\rho)\,d\rho$ for $\rho_0=0.5$. Right plot: comparison of $\int_0^x p_{\rm exact}(\rho)\,d\rho$ and $\int_0^x p_{\rm large}(\rho)\,d\rho$ for $\rho_0=3$. The approximations (orange) are almost indistinguishable from the exact answer (blue).

Comment: Do you have a bound on the accuracy of your approximation of the integral?

Comment: I feel like there is a mistake somewhere here. I0 scales like exp(x)/sqrt(2pi x) which still leaves me with a non-analytic integral.

Comment: the asympotic expansion of  $\rho I_0(2\rho\rho_0)$ gives the exponential of $ 2\rho\rho_0 +(1/2)\log\rho$, and for large $\rho_0$ the log can be neglected.

Comment: Also, as noted in my [other comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449430/approximation-for-a-bessel-function-integral#comment1161367_449430), the expression for $p_{tot}$ in the OP is incorrect.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : According to this [comment by the OP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449430/approximation-for-a-bessel-function-integral#comment1161375_449430), we cannot assume that $\rho_0$ is large.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Each of your three displayed equalities is (at best) only approximate, in a certain sense, which needs to be specified and proved. Also, I don't see your response to my [previous comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449430/approximation-for-a-bessel-function-integral#comment1161384_449439) that the expression for $p_{tot}$ in the OP is incorrect. See also [my most recent comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449430/approximation-for-a-bessel-function-integral#comment1161531_449430), which explains why the expression is incorrect.

Comment: no, I don't have a bound on the accuracy of my approximation to the integral, all I have is the two plots which show the quality of the approximation; I am actually quite pleased that the two curves are so close even when $\rho_0$ is comparable to unity.

Comment: concerning your other comment, on an error in the OP --- I limited myself to the question of the OP to find a "reasonable approximation" to the integral over the Bessel function; how this connects to the "dart board problem" is beyond me.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : It should have been clear at once that the expression for $p_{tot}$ in the OP is incorrect, since e.g. the term $e^{-\rho_0^2}$ in that expression is physically meaningless, as $\rho_0^2$ is not dimensionless. At least, this should be clear now.